# How to access C++ map inner values

Tags: c++, iterator, char, stdmap

This is my map `std::map<std::string,ProductInfo> mymap` and these are the values inside `ProductInfo`:

```
bool isActive = false;
char name[80];
```

I am already able to access a specific key - value pair (`std::string` - `ProductInfo`) using `::iterator` but what I actually need is the `name` property inside `ProductInfo`

[also this is what ProductInfo looks like during debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl6I9.png)

Comment: `mymap["some key"].name`?

Comment: You know that the iterator "points" to a `std::pair` containing the key and the value? And that the value is in the `second` member of the pair? And that this is the actual data-value? Now, how do you think you could access the members of your structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to access the property `name` of the `ProductInfo` object inside a map. What you need to do is `your_map["the key"]->get_name()` where `get_name()` is a getter for `name` in `ProductInfo`.

Comment: This is incorrect and won't compile.

Comment: @AnoopRana The intention was not to give you a code that compiles. The intention was to tell you how to access a class property. I don't quite understand why you marked the response as accepted and saying that it won't compile. Rather strange

Comment: I am not OP. I have not accepted your answer. OP and me are different person. Did you confuse me with OP?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a map:

```
std::map<KeyT, ValueT> m;
```

The value your iterators are pointing to are defined as:

```
using value_type = std::pair<KeyT const, ValueT>;
```

Thus, you use `pair::second` for the mapped value:

```
auto it = m.find("some key");
if (it != m.end()) {
  std::cout << "name: " << it->second.name << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To loop over containers then do not use iterators (or indices) if not explicitly necessary, but use range based for loops (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). Range based are more readable and prevent accidental out of bound access.

For code readability you can use structured bindings (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map> // or unordered_map for faster access
#include <string>

struct ProductInfo
{
    std::size_t id;
};

int main()
{
    // initialize map with 3 entries
    std::map<std::string, ProductInfo> m_products
    {
        {"one",{1}},
        {"two",{2}},
        {"three",{3}}
    };

    // range based for loop with structured bindings
    for (const auto& [key, product_info] : m_products)
    {
        std::cout << "key = " << key << ", value = " << product_info.id << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also do not use the [] index operator as advised above. But use at : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at. The [] operator will insert data if data is not found and this often leads to bugs. The at function will only return data if it really exists inside the map

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a key of a `std::map` using the `operator[]` gives us the **mapped type** which is the same as `ProductInfo` in your example. This means that you can access the data member `name` using the member access operator as shown below:

```
//-----------------------------vvvv---->use member access operator
std::cout << mymap["some key"].name;
```

If you provided getters for `ProductInfo` then you can use that getter as shown below:

```
std::cout << mymap["some key"].get_name();
```

Also note that if the key is not already inside the map, a new key-value pair will be created and inserted inside the map when using `operator[]` so don't forget to initialize each of the data members inside `ProductInfo`.